# How to retrieve multiple data from localStorage at a time and store the data

Tags: javascript, arrays, web, frontend, backend

How do I get all the different key/value pairs stored in the localstorage whenever my window reloads using vanilla JS.And also How to store these data in a object with similar properties which I receive from the localStorage ?
for eg. :
if I have thses 2 things in local storage

```
localStorage.setItem("todoList","Task 1");
localStorage.setItem("doingList","Task 1");
```

Comment: Explain your  question more on what you need and what you tried. ore expected output

Comment: Sorry I made few errors while uploading data to the local storage
Actually I want to store multiple values of 3 keys 
and I want to fetch the data of all the keys and their multiple values when I reload a page and store them to repective posisiton

Answer (score 0):

You can only put one value in a `localStorage` key.

Put the values in an array, convert the array to JSON, and store that.

```
var todoList = ["Task 1","Task 2","Task 3"];
localStorage.setItem("todoList", JSON.stringify(todoList));
```

To retrieve it you call `JSON.parse()`

```
todoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todoList") || "[]");
```

Comment: I tried in the compiler to put 2 different key/value pairs then I got the correct o/p
then I retrieved it using
```
localStorage.getItem("key1");
localStorage.getItem("key2");
```
I got the corect value of the data I stored

Answer (score 0):

Just destruct the `localStorage` and get all Items

```
const items = { ...localStorage };
console.log(items)
```